# PHP/MySQL - Checking results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a login system with PHP, but the SQL query is not returning the result I'm expecting.

I have a typical username and password page, and I'm using what the user types in there to check for an account. I know for a fact that the database contains real usernames and passwords but the call to `mysqli_num_rows` is always returning 0.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM StaffTable WHERE staffNo='$username' AND password='$password'");

echo mysqli_num_rows($result); //This always prints out 0.
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
    echo "OK";
}
```

Comment: Everything is bad in this code: vulnerable to sql injections; storing plain text passwords

Comment: Read this before somebody hits you with an SQL injection - http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Check whether you are getting the POST values in the file or not and also whether the field names are correct.

Comment: @Phil: the only thing is that that article doesn't explain what actually is sql injection :-D "parameterized statement is used to execute the same statement repeatedly with high efficiency" o_O After reading this OP would say "I only run this query once and don't care of efficiency atm, so why would I bother"

Comment: @zerkms OP can google that one for themselves

Comment: I'm fully aware of SQL injection and password hashes. This is simply the first testing version of my code.

Comment: I'll never understand this logic ~ *"I'll do it real bad at first, then spend ages fixing it all up later"* :/

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the *plain-text-password* thing which you claim to be aware of, something like this perhaps...

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;

$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM StaffTable WHERE staffNo = ? AND password = ?');
if (!$stmt) {
    throw new Exception($con->error, $con->errno);
}
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    throw new Exception($stmt->error, $stmt->errno);
}
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo 'OK';
}
```

To summarise...

- I've checked that the input variables are set and assigned defaults if they're not that shouldn't produce any false positives
- I've used a prepared statement with bound parameters to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities
- I throw exceptions when errors occur. These are great because they halt execution and give you all the information you need to debug the problem.

  - This is my main problem with *mysqli* over PDO. *mysqli* is simply not noisy enough when errors occur. You shouldn't have to manually check for error conditions all the time.
- I've changed the query to a simple boolean check as that's all you were using it for. The row either exists, or it doesn't.

Comment: This is in no way a downgrade on your answer seeing as it's good, but to help him out further wouldn't it be more beneficial to help him with a more beginner (no offense OP) answer. I was going to go into classes and functions, but based off the code provided I had thought it would be more appropriate to give him something more his level.

Comment: @MorganGreen Not sure what you mean. I'm only using functions and methods that are party of the *mysqli* extension. This is no more *advanced* than the code in the question. OP is already using a class (`mysqli`). Using the procedural wrapper functions only makes the code longer. Who wants to be prefixing everything with `mysqli_`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something more along the lines of

```
                        $username=$_POST['username'];
                        $password=md5($_POST['password']);
                        $query="SELECT * FROM StaffTable WHERE staffNo='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";
                        $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) 
                            { 
                                echo "Incorrect Password Or Username Combo";

                            }
                        else {
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
                                    $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
                                    }
```

I would say to start with at least running the passwords in encryption for now and look into SQL injection and upgrade as you learn more about what you're looking at.
The biggest flaw in yours aside from what's already been pointed out is

```
($con, "SELECT * FROM StaffTable WHERE staffNo='$username' AND password='$password'");
```

With the variables you cannot put them within the query that way; you would want to do something more along the lines of

```
($con, "SELECT * FROM StaffTable WHERE staffNo='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");
```

If you'll notice I escaped from the plain text so that the variables would be set. The reason you're returning 0 results everytime is because you are actually searching for username $username with $password as their password. 
Good luck!

Comment: 1) How do you know OP is using MD5 (hint: don't ever use MD5 for passwords)? 2) You can indeed interpolate variables into double-quoted strings. The result here would be the same as concatenation.

Comment: 1. I don't. That's why I said it was a good place to start. 2. I have never had a variable work for me within double quoted strings.

Comment: Guess so. I'll stick to escaping regardless.

Comment: concatenation != escaping